# jQuery validations not working for dynamically appended form

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm appending a form after successful AJAX call. When i'm trying to put validations by using id of that form its not working. Below is the example of my code.

HTML

```
<div id="dynamic_form"></div>
```

JavaScript

```
tab +=  '<form id="edu_edit_datails" method="post" action="" name="edu_edit_datails" enctype="multipart/form-data">';
tab +=  '<div class="form-group">';
tab +=  '<label for="course">Course:</label>';
tab +=  '<input type="text" class="form-control" id="course" value="" placeholder="Enter your Course" name="course">';
tab +=  '</div>';
tab +=  '<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary " id="submit_edit_edu_dtls">Submit</button>';
tab +=  '</form>';
$('#dynamic_form').html(tab);
```

Validation on click

```
$(document).on('click', '#submit_edit_edu_dtls' , function(e){
  if($("#edu_edit_datails").valid() == false) {
    alert("fail");
    return false;
  } else {
    alert(success);
    return true; 
  }
});
$("#edu_edit_datails").validate({
  rules: {
    course: "required"
  }
})
```

Any help is greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Comment: Set validation rules after adding them to DOM, i.e. `$('#dynamic_form').html(tab);$("#edu_edit_datails").validate(....)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to validate the form (`.validate`) before you use the `.valid()`

```js
var tab="";
tab +=  '<form id="edu_edit_datails" method="post" action="" name="edu_edit_datails" enctype="multipart/form-data">';
tab +=  '<div class="form-group">';
tab +=  '<label for="course">Course:</label>';
tab +=  '<input type="text" class="form-control" id="course" value="" placeholder="Enter your Course" name="course">';
tab +=  '</div>';
tab +=  '<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary " id="submit_edit_edu_dtls">Submit</button>';
tab +=  '</form>';
$('#dynamic_form').html(tab);
$("#edu_edit_datails").validate({
    rules: {
        course: "required"
    }
})
$(document).on('click', '#submit_edit_edu_dtls' , function(e){
    if($("#edu_edit_datails").valid() == false){
         alert("fail");
         return false;
    }else{
        alert("success");
        return true; 
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.17.0/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<diV id="dynamic_form"></div>
```